# Do I have to fseek several times if I want to access different piece of information in a file?

Tags: c, fseek

> At fixed locations in the file metadata, there are three important
>   integers, each stored using exactly 4 bytes:
>
> At byte offset 10-13, the offset in the bitmap file where the pixel
>   array starts.
>
> At byte offset 18-21, the width of the image, in pixels.
>
> At byte offset 22-25, the height of the image, in pixels.

```
/*
 * Read in the location of the pixel array, the image width, and the image
 * height in the given bitmap file.
 */
void read_bitmap_metadata(FILE *image, int *pixel_array_offset, int *width, int *height) {

    fseek(image, 10, SEEK_SET);
    fread(pixel_array_offset, 4, 1, image);
    fseek(image, 18, SEEK_SET);
    fread(width, 4, 1, image);
    fseek(image, 22, SEEK_SET);
    fread(height, 4, 1, image);

}
```

Do I have to use `fseek` 3 times here, even notice that the width and height are continuously?

Comment: The file pointer is advanced automatically. You only need to seek if the data is not at the current file pointer (or perhaps switching between r/w).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can omit the last `fseek()`.

The `fread()` advances the file position always by the amount of data read. So you only need to `fseek()` when you want to skip some bytes or when you want to seek to a fixed position and you do not care where you currently are.

Since you only skip a few bytes you may as well just do a single `fread()` from offset 0 of 26 bytes into a buffer and then pick the data from the buffer as you need it.

**Endianness warning:** There is one big issue when reading multi-byte integers from a file: Whether this works or not depends on the file-endianness and on the host-endianness. Your code only works when they match. If they do not match you have to swap the bytes after the `fread()` operation. On Linux you have `bswap_32()` for this, or if the endianness in the file is *big endian* (aka *network byte order*) you can use `ntohl()`.

Comment: It might be even more efficient to do a single fread of 26 bytes into a buffer, then memcpy out the 3 interesting parts.  You would still have to mind the endianness issues.

Comment: @AShelly: Fully agreed. Thanks. I added this hint.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using a modern OS (That has virtual memory), then you can use `mmap`, to map the file into memory (not-copy, it uses virtual memory). This will allow you to read/(optionally write), and seek, using memory operations: pointer arithmetic / arrays, in C.

For Unixes (Gnu/Linux, MacOS, BSD, System V), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap and
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

I think even Microsoft's Windows can now do this, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Memory/file-mapping

Comment: It's not portable; can't run on Windows